# how to create a header text that adapts itself to the height and width of viewport

Tags: css

I want to have header text that always takes ( for example) 80% of screen width and 80% of screen height. 
the text should always remain in viewport and adjust it self on windows resize to take the defined viewport size.
I know that i can use(for example) font-size: 30vw to achieve my goal horizontally , but i want the text to adjust it self both vertically and horizontally. 
an similiar example of my desired implementation is www.sels.de (the header text resizes itself to fit viewport horizontally and vertically). 
A jquery plugin or pure css implementation is ok. 
I also know that i can do it using width and height media queries , but it is know to be buggy(so , i am looking for a solution other than that)

Comment: They are definitely using a plugin to do that.  Inspect the text with dev tools (Firebug in Firefox) and look at the html for the text as you resize the window.  Lots of things are being changed on this element, but it looks like they are changing the line height and font size in pixels on resize.  There are links to a few plugins in the head of the page.  I would try to look them up and see which one is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked is just using an image for the text, so that will scale down properly.
Try using em units like `font-size: 16em;` otherwise I would just use media queries like so: (nothing buggy about it)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .header-text {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .header-text {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: as i mentioned in question, this is not the solution, it only adjusts vertical size and i also mentioned that i do not want to use (max-height) and max-width media queries, if you optimise the text for every possible aspect ration it will require several hundred lines of css, i look a solution like the example i have given but text only , no svg ( or other image formats)

Comment: and the provided example is not an image, it is text .

Comment: Yea you're right it is text... with some insane transforms on it and data attributes. And literally exactly what is happening is the font-size is being reduced you can see in the styles. They must do it as a function of all those data attributes so I have no clue. Good luck

Comment: Also you are confusing everyone by saying header text, it's actually the hero image text

Comment: hero text is a nondocumented term, i used the term header https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp to make it more understandable to all.

Comment: it appears that their is no working solution as of now and every one uses hacks and several width and height media queries like me( i have tested a number of jquery plugin (including bigtext and a few more but they do not work for my purpose). 
i will write a jquery plugin  to calculate text height and with based on viewport size  when i find time for it

Answer (score 0):

This header looks like action of http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

If you need something similar and don't have time to create, this is the best way.

Comment: as you may have read the question , i am not lookig for navbar, i am looking for heading text

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I'm understanding correctly it may be easier than I originally thought.  Have you tried just setting the `font-size: 80vh;`?

See this fiddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zr5hez5j/)

Comment: as i mentioned i want the text to be vertically and horizontally in viewport, yes i did tried your and several other methods, but try to test your fiddle on a small width screen, one would have to vertically scroll to see the text and that is what i do not want to happen. 
i want the text decrease its size if it can not fit in device height and width

Comment: Vertically and horizontally what???  Its hard to understand what you are looking for.  Did you try this in a regular html page?  Its scrolling in the fiddles because they are in "frames"  If you were to put that code into a blank html page the text would *never* go off screen as long as it was less than 100vh.  Thats the whole point of vh.

Comment: I know what vh means, i know what vw means, i know it as well that what i want cannot be achieved with simple lines of css.

Comment: I do achieve my goal with several media queries , but i was looking for some thing better, as i replied to other answer in this page. After reading all answers here  the only solution for me is to write a jquery plugin of my own which calculates font size based on height and width of page. 
I will do it in my spare time
Some thing like http://fittextjs.com/ but which also resizes font based on vertical viewport size, not just horizontal